# SQL to generate common sequence for each group

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

i have below data.

```
a_id    state   date

1   A   7/5/19

1   A   7/6/19

1   M   7/7/19

1   M   7/8/19

1   A   7/9/19

1   A   7/10/19

1   A   7/11/19

1   M   7/12/19
```

i want to generate a sequence using SQL for each group in the order they arrived.

for example there are 2 groups for A as they didnt arrive in the same sequence. similarly for M. 
See the expected output below.

```
a_id    state   date    result col

1   A   7/5/19  1

1   A   7/6/19  1

1   M   7/7/19  2

1   M   7/8/19  2

1   A   7/9/19  3

1   A   7/10/19 3

1   A   7/11/19 3

1   M   7/12/19 4
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when state = prev_state then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by a_od order by date) as result
from (select t.*,
             lag(state) over (partition by a_id order by date) as prev_state
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: thanks for the qucik turn aroung Gordon.
it wont work as there can be multiple ap_id's

Comment: @VishalChavhan . . . (1) Nothing in your question is called `ap_id`.  (2) Multiple `a_id`s work fine with this code.